# Pasarela de pago Stripe con PHP

Tags: php

Necesito montar un webservice en php para una pasarela de pago con Stripe, he estado mirando la documentación pero no me queda claro ni lo he conseguido hacer funcionar.

Adjunto el código que tengo actualmente por si alguien me puede ayudar y me sabe decir que estoy haciendo mal..

```
   <?php
namespace Stripe;
require ('./lib/Stripe.php');

    Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_LfhRwV55b8XFSDf0mIEIGXft");
     $token = Token::create([
                            "card" => [
                                "number" => "4242424242424242",
                                "exp_month" => 2,
                                "exp_year" => 2020,
                                "cvc" => "314"
                                    ]
                            ]);

  $error = '';
  $success = '';
  try {

      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => 1000,
                                "currency" => "eur",
                                "card" =>  $token ));
    $success = 'Your payment was successful.';
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Es lógico que no funcione. Estas lanzando una Excepction directamente con `throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");`

Comment: Cierto, tanto quitar y modificar el codigo se me ha quedado ahi la expeción, aún con la expepación quitada no funciona :(